# Swift and terminal: Using Google Endpoints in an iOS Client

Tags: terminal, google-cloud-endpoints

I am following the tutorial at

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/calling-from-ios

and when I get to step 5 and Open a new Terminal window to invoke ServiceGenerator. I get the error message in my terminal saying..

Barrys-MacBook-Pro:~ barrymadej$ /Users/barrymadej/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceGenerator-avaeguyitgyhxpcnaejpgzvxezei/Build/Products/Debug/ServiceGenerator \

> /Users/barrymadej/Documents/AndroidStudioProjects/StudentProgressTrackerDatabaseAndCloud/backend/build/discovery-docs/myApi-v2-rpc.discovery /
>   ERROR: An output directory is required.

Usage: ServiceGenerator [FLAGS] [ARGS]

Required Flags:

```
--outputDir PATH
    The destination directory for writing the generated files.
```

Optional Flags:

```
--discoveryService URL
    Instead of discovery's default URL, use the specified URL as the
    location to send the JSON-RPC requests. This is useful for running
    against a custom or prerelease server.

--gtlFrameworkName NAME
    Will generate sources that include GTL's headers as if they are in a
    framework with the given name. If you are using GTL via CocoaPods,
    you'll likely want to pass "GoogleAPIClient" as the value for this.

--apiLogDir DIR
    Write out a file into DIR for each JSON API description processed. These
    can be useful for reporting bugs if generation fails with an error.

--httpLogDir PATH
    Turn on the HTTP fetcher logging and set it to write to PATH. This can
    be useful for diagnosing errors on discovery fetches.

--generatePreferred
    Causes the list of services to be collected, and all preferred services
    to be generated.

--httpHeader NAME:VALUE
    Causes the given NAME/VALUE pair to be added as an HTTP header on *all*
    HTTP requests made by the generator. Can be used repeatedly to provide
    additional header pairs.

--formattedName SERVICE:VERSION=NAME
    Causes the given SERVICE:VERSION pair to override its service name in
    files, classes, etc. with NAME. If :VERSION is omitted the override is
    for any version of the service. Can be used repeatedly to provide
    several maps when generating a few things in a single run.

--addServiceNameDir yes|no  Default: no
    Causes the generator to add a directory with the service name in the
    outputDir for the files. This is useful for generating multiple
    services.

--generatedDir yes|no  Default: no
    Causes a directory in outputDir called "Generated" to be created and
    used to contain the generated files.

--removeUnknownFiles yes|no  Default: no
    By default, the generator will report unknown files in the output
    directory, as commonly happens when classes go away in a new API
    version. This option causes the generator to also remove the unknown
    files.

--rootURLOverrides yes|no  Default: yes
    Causes any API root URL for a Google sandbox server to be replaced with
    the googleapis.com root instead.

--verbose
    Generate more verbose output. Can be used more than once.
```

Arguments:

```
Multiple arguments can be given on the command line.

service:version
    The description of the given [service]/[version] pair is fetched and the
    files for it are generated. When using --generatePreferred version can
    be '-' to skip generating the name service.

http[s]://url/to/rpc_description_json
    A URL to download containing the description of a service to generate.

path/to/rpc_description.json
    The path to a text file containing the description of a service to
    generate.
```

ServiceGenerator path:

/Users/barrymadej/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceGenerator-avaeguyitgyhxpcnaejpgzvxezei/Build/Products/Debug/ServiceGenerator
ERROR: There was one or more errors; check the full output for details.
Barrys-MacBook-Pro:~ barrymadej$ --outputDir
-bash: --outputDir: command not found
Barrys-MacBook-Pro:~ barrymadej$ /Users/barrymadej/Documents/AndroidStudioProjects/StudentProgressTrackerDatabaseAndCloud/API

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Hopefully my tags are more appropriate now.

Answer (score 0):

You should generate a REST discovery document and use [the new Objective C client](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/wiki/ServiceGenerator) instead. The client library you're trying to use is deprecated anyway. It looks like it didn't work because you specified the flag without the rest of the command, though.

Comment: Thanks, As far as I am aware, I had generated the REST discovery documents. I will try with the are objective C client instead.